# What is the best way to Zip NSData with a password?

Tags: ios, objective-c, zip

While researching the subject I found a few libraries that may be helpful in this:

1. Objective-zip
2. ZipArchive
3. SSZipArchive

There's probably more?!

All I need is to zip NSData created from an NSString; either encrypt it or password protect it and then send via the email.

Any known issues with any of these libraries? Is there a rule of thumb as to using one over another? So far I am leaning towards the Objective-zip, but I don't have much experience in that area.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to document the solution here.

I ended up using both ZipArchive and Objective-zip as they kinda compliment each other with different functionality. I am using password protection of Objective-zip library, and appending NSData into the created zip file of ZipArchive library.

Including both does seem a little redundant, but seem to work fine.

Comment: I'v been struggling with this ymotov. Can you please post some sample code here...

Answer (score 0):

Objective-Zip seems to be the one you want. ZipArchive is outdated and not maintained. SSZipArchive doesn't have support for creating password-protected zip files.